# jQuery one button loop to show/hide sibling elements

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to use one button to show/hide through an un-order list of elements in a looping fashion. Page loads, first element is shown, click button, shown element is hidden and the next is shown... kinda like clicking next in a slideshow. The problem is I don't know how to stop or reset the click function after the first if statement. Triggering the function now rips through them all. Can someone take a look at my code and give me a hand please?

```
var daily = '.daily_goal_activity li';   

$(daily).addClass(function (index) {
        return "item-" + index;
    });
    $('.item-0').show();
});

$('#activity_toggle').click(function () {
    $(daily).hide();

    if ($(daily).hasClass('item-0')) {
        $('.item-1').show();
    }
    if ($(daily).hasClass('item-1')) {
        $('.item-2').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could `return;` from the function inside each `if` statement, but the entire approach seems like the wrong route to go.

Comment: If they are list elements, then they are siblings, right? Just get a reference to the currently visible element, hide it and show the next sibling.

Comment: @FelixKling I was working on the same theory, too. Doesn't seem to be an easy way to cycle back around to the first element, though.

Comment: @Anthony: It's not that difficult, have a look at my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are list elements, then they are siblings, right?

You can just get a reference to the currently visible element, hide it and show the next sibling.

Assuming all list elements are initially hidden, and only the element with the class `current` is visible, then it would be something like:

```
var $daily = $('.daily_goal_activity li');
$daily.first().addClass('current');

$('#activity_toggle').click(function () {
    $daily.filter('.current')
      .removeClass('current')
      .next('li').addClass('current');
});
```

If you want to cycle through the elements, you can check whether there actually is a next sibling and if not, go back to the first one:

```
var $next = $daily.filter('.current')
    .removeClass('current')
    .next('li');

if($next.length === 0) {
    $next = $daily.first();
}

$next.addClass('current');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hbqbu/)

Comment: Perfect thanks, Felix. I knew I was sorta dancing around a solution, but had obviously ran out of ideas on my own.

Answer (score 1):

A few points.

1. Storing `'.daily_goal_activity li'` and reusing it doesn't really save you anything.  You really want to store the selector and reuse that:
   `var daily = $('.daily_goal_activity li');`
2. `.hasClass('item-0')` will always be true, because one of the `li`s will have the class `item-0`, as you applied that class in `.addClass()`.
3. To make your code work in its current form, you want to hide `x` and show `x+1`.  You could use a global var to track `x`.
4. You are better off using the structure of the html to track next/previous for you:

```
var daily = $('.daily_goal_activity li');

daily.hide().first().show();

$('#activity_toggle').click(function () {
    var nextdaily = daily.filter(':visible').hide().next();
    if(nextdaily.length > 0) {
        nextdaily.show();
    } else {
        daily.first().show();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/yRFba/

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe you are looking something like this:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3pkum/)

```
   var changeClass=function(){

   if($('ul li.active').length==0){
    $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
    }
else if($('.active').index()==4){
    $('.active').removeClass('active')
    $('ul li:first').addClass('active');
}
else{
     $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active')
     }

  }

     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.button').click(function(){

     changeClass();

     });
 });
```

Comment: You should maybe mention that your code assumes that there are four list elements... better would be a solution that does not depend on the number of elements.

Comment: You are right Felix I didn't mention that...Your solution is better:)

Answer (score 0):

```
var daily = $('.daily_goal_activity li');   
daily.addClass(function (index) { return "item-" + index; }).hide();
$('.item-0').show();

$('#activity_toggle').click(function () {
    daily_num = daily.filter(':visible').index();
    daily.hide().eq(daily_num+1).show();
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7Q6be/)

Answer (score 0):

Single button to toggle Hide/Show

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var id=$("button").attr("id");
        if(id=="hide")
        {
                $("#example").hide();
                $(this).html("Show");
                $(this).attr({"id":"show"});

        }
        else
        {
             $("#example").show();
             $(this).html("Hide");
             $(this).attr({"id":"hide"});
        }



      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <button id="hide">Hide</button>
    <p id="example">Hide me out</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```